# Sample from probabilities based on column values for a large data.frame

Tags: r, sampling, large-data

I can't find anything specific to my question so I hope someone can help me.
I have a data frame (3 million + records ) that contains three columns that contain the probabilities of each "event" occurring. So a basic example for one record is the chance that A happens is 30%, B 20% and C 50%.

So basically each observation has a probability of being A, B or C. This probability depends on the values in column A, B and C.

Below is one way of ding it, where it samples from the columns A,B and C and then assign the sampled value to column "Answer". BUT for 3 million records it just wont work at all.

```
nRowsDf <- nrow(df)
for(i in 1:nRowsDf){
   df[i,c("Answer")] <- sample(sample(c('A','B','C'), size = 1000,
     replace = TRUE, prob = c(df[i,"A_prop"],df[i,"B_prop"], df[i,"C_prop"]))
   ,1)
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way than putting it in a slow loop that will run for +-30 hours.

I have in the mean time switched to excel, not want to go there. But this is what I'm kind of doing in excel, with some modifications : [How To Generate Random Value Based On Assigned Probability In Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4486-excel-random-with-probability.html)

Comment: One has to wonder why you need that. Why are you sampling one value from a sample of 1000 values? Why not simply sampling one value to begin with?

Comment: Hi Roland, jip one has to wonder. : )  Found the example on multiple sites and seeing that I'm not mush of a statistician I kind of kept with it, seeing that it works very well. But still stuck with the original problem, tried something in excel that kind of works, but man I'll be honest I'll rather want to work in R.

Comment: Could you explain what the code is intended to do?

Comment: Hi Whuber, the code: first I get the number of records in the data frame, then I loop over each row in the data frame, where i is the row, and assign an event for each row based on the values in column A, B and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `R` version of the Excel method you reference will process your data in a quarter second--I hope that's fast enough.

```
  df$Answer <- with(df, names(df)[1 + rowSums(cbind(A, A+B, A+B+C) < runif(n))])
```

It uses `runif` to generate uniform random values between 0 and 1 and compares them to the cumulative sums of the probabilities in the data frame, row by row, exactly as the Excel solution does.  Instead of using the `cumsum` function in `R`, though, it's about a hundred times faster (in this example) to compute those sums explicitly with array addition, as shown in the call to `cbind`.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used apply with a costume function.

```
samp <- function(a){  if (sum(a) == 100){
sample(sample(c('A','B',"C"), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(a)),1)  }  
else{   0  }
}
df$answer <- apply(df[,1:3],1, FUN = samp)
```

Done 3.3 million records in 2 min.

Thanks for the help whuber, your method works very good, but I thought this is a good opportunity to learn more about the apply functions.